# 3D Scatter Plot on Basemap in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a 3D scatter plot of a smoke plume in python with a map of North America underneath. 
I've tried various methods but all seem to have there downfalls. 
My code at the moment is:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,4))
ax = Axes3D(fig)

M = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-140,llcrnrlat=10,urcrnrlon=-40,urcrnrlat=70,
        projection='cyl', resolution ='c',area_thresh=100.)
ax.add_collection3d(M.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5))
ax.add_collection3d(M.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5))
ax.add_collection3d(M.drawparallels(np.arange(35,65,5),labels=[1,0,0,0]))

date = save_dir[-10:]
tau = tau_mod.int2tau(date)
dt = tau_mod.tau2time(tau)

q = ax.plot(max_x, max_y, max_z, c = 'black', lw = 3)

y,x=M(y,x)

p = ax.scatter(x,y,z,lw = 0,c = conc ,alpha = 0.75, s = 40,
                norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(),vmin = 20,
               vmax = 4000, marker = ',',zorder=2)


ax.view_init(azim = a ,elev = e)


cb = fig.colorbar(p)
cb.set_label('CO [ppb]')
cmin , cmax = cb.get_clim()
ticks = np.linspace(cmin,cmax,10)
for t in range(len(ticks)):
    ticks[t] = int("%i" % ticks[t])
cb.set_ticks(ticks)
cb.set_ticklabels(ticks)

ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax.set_zlabel('Altitude [km]')
plt.show()
```

The two main problems I get are:
The scatter plot doesn't appear on the map - you can see it off in the distance outside the axis boundaries.
The drawparallels doesn't work - it appears with this message:
't=ax.text(xlab,yy[n],latlab,horizontalalignment='right',verticalalignment='center',**kwargs)
TypeError: text() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)' (I've never had this problem using this command in a 2D plot).

I have also tried just plotting an png image of the map using ax.plot_surface but that produces a problem with the order of the image - it seems to plot the surface image over the scatter plot no matter what zorders I use.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like (at least in part) a missing latlon=True in your scatter function.